# How to install several IDE version on my PC

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, ide

How can i install old version of IDE, without uninstalling the other version?(How can i install several IDE version in same laptop).

Comment: Avoid asking multiple questions, https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and what research have you done?

Answer (score 3):

Arduino.cc have a guide :

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/PortableIDE

The gist is:

1. Download the desired version in ZIP format
2. Unpack the content in the zip file to a folder
3. Start the arduino.exe in that folder.

Remember that you have to place all libraries, board definitions in that folder.

The folder can be copied to another computer or a USB stick....

Comment: Note that it's not required to run in portable mode. If you want each IDE installation to be isolated then that's the thing to do but if you want them to share preferences and hardware packages installed via Boards Manager then you should not use portable mode.